# If I participate in a ERC20 ICO with my Metamask eth address, can I add the custom token later on?

Tags: erc-20, metamask, etherscan, ico

If I have not added the ICO's token to my Metamask yet as a custom token, can I do it after the token distribution? Like claiming my tokens after it's been sent, by adding the new custom token to my Metamask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a token to MetaMask (or any other wallet interface for that matter) does not "claim" the tokens. It simply tells MetaMask to look at that specific token for any balance. You can always receive tokens on your address, and add it to MetaMask later on in order to see your balance.